# How to convert from DataTime Json to Epoch int using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a REST api call and I'm parsing the response to POJOs using GSON.  One field (`updatedAt`) is a `DateTime` field which I'd like to store as a timeInMs integer value in my POJO. I'm unsure how to do this without having to write extra classes to accommodate, and maintain a load of boilerplate code.  I'm using code generation in my app and so writing superfluous wrapper classes isn't an option.

I have a fair few classes which I'm going to need to apply this transformation to, so don't want to have to write custom (de)serialiser for each.

I really need a way of telling gson to directly convert the DateTime into an int when it comes across a a field named "updatedAt".

For example, this is the field in my Rest API response - `{...."updatedAt":"2014-08-31T18:43:09.681Z"...}`

and in my POJO I have

```
public class SomeClass {
...
  private int timeInMs;
...
}
```

How do I seamlessly convert from string in my Json to an int in my object?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that `Date.getTime()` returns a long, so your `timeInMs` field should be a long, not an int.

With regards to your actual question, you can split your JSON deserialisation into two parts: parsing the JSON into a `JsonElement` and then marshalling that into an instance of `SomeClass`. In between these two steps, you could inspect the `JsonElement` to see if it contains the appropriate field, and if so add a new field.

Unfortunately doing this in a safe way is quite long-winded:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String json = "{\"someField\":\"someValue\", \"updatedAt\":\"2014-08-31T18:43:09.681Z\"}";

// Parse the JSON into a JsonElement
JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(json);

 // Check top-level element is an object
if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

    // Check updatedAt field exists and value is primitive
    JsonElement updatedAtElement = jsonObject.get("updatedAt");
    if (updatedAtElement != null && updatedAtElement.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        JsonPrimitive updatedAtPrimitive = updatedAtElement.getAsJsonPrimitive();

        // Check value of updatedAt field is a String
        if (updatedAtPrimitive.isString()) {
            String updatedAt = updatedAtPrimitive.getAsString();

            // Try to parse the updatedAt value and set timeInMs
            try {
                Date updatedAtDate = dateFormat.parse(updatedAt);
                long timeInMs = updatedAtDate.getTime();
                jsonObject.addProperty("timeInMs", timeInMs);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid updatedAt date: " + updatedAt);
            }

        }
    }
}

// Use the (possibly modified) JsonElement to create an instance of SomeClass
SomeClass someInstance = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, SomeClass.class);
```

If you don't want to be able to get the value of the `updatedAt` field at all after setting `timeInMs`, you can also call `jsonObject.remove("updatedAt")` to remove that field entirely.